# Looking for old sci-fi book about Dulgari Empire

Tags: story-identification, aliens

Looking for 50+ year old sci fi book. The Dulgari (sp?) empire has the humans on the run. The hero is a military man who has battled the Dulgari. There are always more of their ships than ours. The initial battle he goes through a series of pre-programmed ship movements, to a draw. Ends up tricking aliens to bring fleet to earth. He signals a "drive mechanism" to start that blows up sun and destroys their fleet and give humans advantage. I remember there being a drink called the "9 Planets".

Comment: A question -- are you saying that the hero of the story lures the aliens close to Earth, and then blows up our own sun? Does this mean that all humans on Planet Earth would have died as a result, and only humans living on other worlds, in other solar systems, would have survived?

Comment: Yes. In the book, humans on earth had developed abilities such as telepathy. Mars and the other colonies have been emptied and they end up on a huge craft heading out at light speed to populate and help the rest of earth's colonies (not Sol).

Comment: Note that duplicate target has another closed duplicate pointing to it. Please avoid creating duplicate chains.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"The Solarians" by Norman Spinrad (1966).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Solarians

> The novel takes places centuries in the future when humanity has colonized many star systems. Another race, the Duglaari or "Doogs" is slowly conquering human systems

...

> When all seems lost, a stardrive in a ship on Mercury is activated, and Sol explodes, annihilating the Doog fleet.

It also features the drink you mention: 9 Planets. It's a nine layered drink, the punchline being that the ninth layer sobers you up!

Comment: Wait... Sol explodes?! That would wipe out the entire system...

Comment: @Tim, yes. But there was a <spoiler> that meant it wasn't as bad as it seemed.

Comment: Interesting, I wonder if JMS stole this for the backstory of Babylon 5. There is a warlike race, the Dilgar, who rampage around but are eventually driven back to their home planet. As part of the surrender terms, Earth warships blockade them and trap the Dilgar there. Shortly after that, their sun goes nova, vaporising the Dilgar homeworld and wiping out (almost) the entire species. A lot of surprising parallels to this tale. An homeage, perhaps?

Comment: @Tim It was a deliberate plan by the natives of the lost Sol . They had actually all fled the system in a fleet of ships but that is only revealed at the end

Comment: @sabbahillel so what you're saying is JMS didn't rip this off when he storied the Dilgar, he ripped it off when he storied the Black Star?  :)

Comment: Thanks to Moriarity for answering a question that sits there now and then at the edge of my thoughts as I fall asleep. Well done and thank you!